# How do I prevent a program from alt-tabbing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse-click

I play a game which requires constant swiping (CS:GO). However, when I hold left click and swipe down, the game alt-tabs. I know it's because the mouse goes out of the game and clicks the desktop, but I don't know how to prevent it. (I only have one monitor). Does anyone know how to prevent this? Or do I have to use some sort of software (not asking for)? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't an easy way.  A program would have to be design to specifically capture this shortcut then do nothing with it in order to stop Windows from capturing it.

Comment: If you are shooting in CS:GO (left mouse) and drag the mouse down is what happened? I play CS Source / GO since many many years and didn't have such an issue ...

Comment: are you playing in fullscreen? 'cause your mouse shouldn't be able to focus your desktop if you are playing in fullscreen. also, "alt-tabbing" refers to pressing ALT+TAB, what you mean is defocus or something like that.

Comment: I know it is strange but I have confirmed that that's what happens. I could play fullscreen windows but that strongly affects the FPS and makes other video settings inaccessible. So yes, the focus gets transfered to the desktop and so the game tabs out.